# node.js child_process.spawn output to console odd format

Tags: node.js, console, console.log

I'm trying to write a small wrapper to execute a shell command via nodejs and print the output of the command to the console. so far I'm pretty much done, but the format of the output in the console is... awkward and and I have no idea why. :(

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

MyWrapper( "ls", ["-l"], function(text) {

        console.log(text)
        fs.appendFileSync('testlog.txt', text)
});

function MyWrapper(cmd, args, callBack) {

        var child = spawn(cmd, args)
        var response = ""

        child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { response += buffer.toString() });
        child.stdout.on('end', function() { callBack (response) });
}
```

testlog.txt is totally fine:

```
total 5
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 user user   114 Feb 26 23:09 test.git
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 user user  7524 Feb 27 12:45 testlog.txt
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 user user   524 Feb 27 01:17 test.txt
```

But the console output is:

```
total 5

drwxrwxr-x+ 1 mmay mmay  114 Feb 26 23:09 test.git

                                                  -rw-rw-r--+ 1 git  git  7750 Feb 27 12:47 testlog.txt

                                                                                                        -rw-rw-r--+ 1 git  git   524 Feb 27 01:17 test.txt
```

And I have no idea how to fix it... any hint would be awesome :)

Comment: You mean whitespaces before lines? Examine buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Buffer was fine, little  me was stupid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uuuh, made a stupid mistake.

Script was called via *command* in *authorized_keys* on login. And there was the *no-pty* flag too.